# Kendo ui scheduler align issue in Google chrome 64.0 version

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having design issue occurred once my chrome is upgraded. It is working properly in later version of chrome. Can anyone helpe please?

Here is image link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JhIhEsI7MgS1Ng6WGGaI7FCDGFGkqVPf/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: How do you expect anyone to know what the problem is? "It is working in a later version of chrome" isn't much help... Also posting images only makes this question harder for other people with whatever issue you are finding later to find.

Comment: Totally agree with Steve - I have checked Kendo Scheduler demos and it works correctly in newest Chrome even in Canary at my side. In such cases it is much recommended to share some isolated [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/) where the issue can be replicated.

Comment: Don't get frustrated gyus. I got the solution. I am new to kendo ui. And not getting solution. That's why asked.

Comment: @user9397697 how you make it to work?